# Actionscript 3 - Rotation of an object moving between 2 points

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation

im basically creating a moving object which shoots a bullet at another moving object. I can get the bullet to move correctly but can't figure out how to calculate the rotation to make the bullet go in a straight line between the two, regardless of their individual rotation.

Here is a short vid of what I mean: http://i.gyazo.com/06c6f4c98391589609f495277bab8b3f.mp4

Here is the code that is used for the creation of the bullet.

```
private function createBullet(): void {

            _startX = this.x  
            _startY = this.y 
            _endX = (Init._player.x); 
            _endY = (Init._player.y); 
            var tempBullet: MovieClip = new Bullet();
            tempBullet.vx = (_endX - _startX) / _bulletSpeed;
            tempBullet.vy = (_endY - _startY) / _bulletSpeed;
            tempBullet.x = _startX;
            tempBullet.y = _startY;
            tempBullet.rotation = ???
            tempBullet.startX = _startX;
            tempBullet.startY = _startY;
            tempBullet.maxDistance = _maxDistance;
            _bullets.push(tempBullet);
            stage.addChild(tempBullet);
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is work out the angle between two points. The two points in this case are the bullets position and the position on the last frame. You can do that like this:

```
var dx:Number = oldBullet.x - bullet.x;
var dy:Number = oldBullet.y - bullet.y;
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

dx and dy are just the deltas of the x and y, so you could also use the x and y velocity of the bullet instead.